# Something similar to map tag in css?

Tags: html, css, image

So, I need two small parts of my header to be clickable. The problem is that I can't use map tag because my image is set in css as a background of a div. And I'm not allowed to change that (to use img src instead). How can I do that, without using absolute positioning of two divs behind the image.

css:

```
#bg_top { /*the design for the header*/
    background:url(../images/header_bg_new.png) center top  no-repeat;
    min-height: 100%; /*stick footer to bottom of the page*/
    text-align:left;
    width:100%;
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Their is a trick for solving this problem...

In the div#bg_top add a transparent gif image which should be of dimension 1x1 and then assign its width and height in img tag...

```
<div id="bg_top"><img src="spacer.gif" width="100%" height="100%" /></div>
```

and then add map tag in it...
This is a simple trick you can use...

You can apply img tag via jquery also,

```
$("#bg_top").html("<img src='spacer.gif' width='100%' height='100%' />");
```

Download image from this link:- [Spacer.gif](ftp://ftp.bignosebird.com/spacer.gif)